# Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "Unsupported origin type 'Image' is set for '

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to click the default images using ios appium, but java sends the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "Unsupported origin type 'Image' is set for '{
    duration = 100;
    origin = Image;
    type = pointerMove;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}' action item. Supported origin types: (
    pointer,
    viewport
) or an element instance" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unsupported origin type 'Image' is set for '{
    duration = 100;
    origin = Image;
    type = pointerMove;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}' action item. Supported origin types: (
    pointer,
    viewport
) or an element instance}
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'sprout24.local', ip: '192.168.1.73', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
```

this is my code that causes that.

```
  List<WebElement> dp = driver.findElementsByClassName("XCUIElementTypeImage");

System.out.println("default pic found");
Actions build4 = new Actions(driver); 
build4.moveToElement(dp.get(0)).build().perform();
```

i am using Actions class because the attribute is set to visible=false, even the element is on the screen.

I have tried also with

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
        action.singleTap(dp.get(0));
        action.perform();
```

But it also fails

Answer (score 2):

As i can see, you are working with iOS device, right? If so as far as i know appium doesnt support Actions class for all iOS versions, if you want to scroll the screen, you better use that:

```
JavascriptExecutor js;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
```

this code will scroll you screen down (or up if you type "up" in the direction field value).
In advance, regarding

```
List<WebElement> dp = driver.findElementsByClassName("XCUIElementTypeImage");
```

If you would like to check an element for the existance, you better use methods:

```
driver.findElements(By.name("")).isEmpty();
```

or

```
driver.findElementsByAccessibilityId(...).isEmpty();
```

in this way you will not get NoSuchElementException and element doest not exist.

Comment: Sorry,  but i am not getting, nosuchelementexception, the element is found, the error i get is the one described in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution:

```
        List<WebElement> dp = driver.findElementsByClassName("XCUIElementTypeImage");
        Point point = dp.get(0).getLocation();
        PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger");
        Sequence sequence = new Sequence(finger, 1);
        sequence.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(1), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), point.x, point.y));
        driver.perform(Arrays.asList(sequence));
```